# Button Background Image change on click

Tags: android, button

I have a button that begins life "Unticked" with text going to a Label that says "NO". When you push the button it changes the image to "Ticked" and displays text in a Label as "YES". This all works perfectly. What I can't do or find is how to change it back to "Unticked" and "NO" if I then push it again?

Here is the code for the button:

```
View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler9 = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.androidnearmisson);


            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            text.setText("YES");

        }
    };
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get TextView's current text and make a comparison. If its YES, change to NO, else vice verse:

```
View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler9 = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        if(text.getText().toString().equals("NO")){
            button9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.androidnearmisson);
            text.setText("YES");
        }
        else {
            button9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.otherimage);  //Replace otherimage with proper drawable id
            text.setText("NO");
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think setting a boolean variable and check that value is better than checking a plain String.

Answer (score 0):

First move this code to your `onCreate` :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Inside your `onClick` :

```
if(text.getText().toString().equals("NO"))
{
   button9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.androidnearmisson);
   text.setText("YES");
}
else
{
   //change what you want
}
```